# Creating postgreSQL database with PgMex from Matlab and loading from Grafana

Tags: postgresql, docker, matlab, grafana

I am using PgMex for writing a postgreSQL database from Matlab data. It connects to a docker (hence the port 5432).

```
import com.allied.pgmex.pgmexec;
dbConn=com.allied.pgmex.pgmexec('connect','host=localhost user=postgres port=5432 password= dbname=postgres');

pgmexec('exec',dbConn,'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS demo');
pgmexec('exec',dbConn,'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS demo.demo_table');
pgmexec('exec',dbConn,['CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demo.demo_table ('...
    'x float8,'...
    'y float8)'])

SData=struct();
SData.x=rand(4,1);
SData.y=rand(4,1);

pgmexec('batchParamExec',dbConn,'INSERT INTO demo.demo_table VALUES ($1,$2)','%float8 %float8',SData);
pgResult = pgmexec('exec',dbConn,'SELECT * FROM  demo.demo_table')
```

I would like to check that the data is well written to the database, and I therefore open the SQL shell:

```
Server [localhost]
Database [postgres]
Port [5432]
Username [postgres]
```

(No password required anymore using https://commandprompt.com/education/how … res-user/)

When calling,

```
SELECT * FROM demo.demo_table
```

there is no nothing. I can't find it either with \l.
Any help on what is going wrong here ?

This is the same when trying to load the database from Grafana. After having loaded the PostgreSQL database, I cannot find the table demo_table from the Grafana interface, in plotting.